# pass function to components in React

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we use a component `Abc` as:

```
<Abc>
{
   param => {xxx}   //  anonymous arrow function 
}
</Abc>
```

so how does `Abc` component use the anonymous function internally? I mean inside the `Abc` component's source code,

```
export class Abc extends Component {

   ...
   this.??.??   // how to invoke the anonymous function whenthe function doesn't even have a name?
}
```

Comment: `this.props.children()`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children

Comment: You can do this with all props, not just children: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a technique called [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

```
function Abc({ children }) {
  return children('data from abc')
}
```

that you can use as

```
<div>
  <Abc>{dataFromAbc => dataFromAbc}</Abc>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that

```
<Abc>{dataFromAbc => dataFromAbc}</Abc>
```

is sort of equivalent as

```
<Abc children={dataFromAbc => dataFromAbc} />
```

so your function can be called from the `children` props. `this.props.children()` if you are in a class component.